# Dynamically concatenate observables

Tags: c#, linq, observable, system.reactive

I use .NET's observables / LINQ and I want to do a pretty simple thing. In my app, I get lists of Media objects:

```
WebinarMedias = typesRepository.GetWebinarMedias();
```

This will be an `IObservable<IList<Media>>`. We're in a view model, I pass that down to a view, which will do the subscription (these are cold observables when created in the view model).
There, it's fine, the view wants Medias.

But sometimes I have *Packages*:

```
typesRepository.GetMonthlyFocusPackages() // IObservable<IList<Package>>
```

From a Package, I can get Medias:

```
packagesRepository.GetPackageMedias(package.Id) // IObservable<IList<Media>>
```

---

*What I want:* in the view model, get packages, reduce to a list of all the medias they include in one `IObservable<IList<Media>>` variable, and display in the view.

More visually:

```
input = [package 1 { media 1, media 2 }, package 2 { media 3 }]
output = [media 1, media 2, media 3]
```

Something like that:

```
var allMedias = typesRepository.GetMonthlyFocusPackages()
    .SomeMagicSelect(packages => packages.Select(p => packagesRepository.GetPackageMedias(p.Id)));
```

I could do foreaches and use more classic code for sure but I'd like to keep the observable cold and keep the value reactive from end to end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
IObservable<IList<Media>> query =
(
    from packages in typesRepository.GetMonthlyFocusPackages()
    from package in packages.ToObservable()
    from medias in typesRepository.GetPackageMedias(package.Id)
    from media in medias.ToObservable()
    select media
).ToList();
```

I recommend doing this, though, as it gives you results in a more even manner as they are computed:

```
IObservable<Media> query =
    from packages in typesRepository.GetMonthlyFocusPackages()
    from package in packages.ToObservable()
    from medias in typesRepository.GetPackageMedias(package.Id)
    from media in medias.ToObservable()
    select media;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this seems to break the observable, .Subscribe() has no effect anymore (I receive no data).
Also, the final signature of the expression is `Media` where I would expect `IList<Media>` (an observable of a list of medias, not an observable of medias).

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling - I gave you the query you asked for first `IObservable<IList<Media>>`, but I recommended the second query `IObservable<Media>` as a better way to provide the results. Just ignore the second query if you don't want it that way.

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling - How are you instantiating your `typesRepository` object? Is it `IDisposable`? Can you show that code in your question please?

Comment: Yes I tested the second query, and adapted it like this: https://pastebin.com/UpHyG7Sc - but it does not yield any value.
I first ignored the first query because I thought ToList() would return an IList and consume the observable, but I see that's an extension method that returns an observable.
But in any case they do not produce values, while the repositories themselves, tested separately, are working fine.

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling - Your query in pastebin is of type `IObservable<IList<Media>>`, but I suspect your other queries return a single `IList<Media>` whereas the pastebin query would return multiple `IList<Media>`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling - Can you also let me know about the life-cycle of `typesRepository` in your code? Is it disposable? Where do you create it? Dispose of it? etc.

Comment: whoops, said nothing, an exception is thrown by GetPackageMedias that gets swallowed into the void. That's why the observable stays quiet.
Apart that your query seems effectively fine. I will just check that everything is fine after I fix the exception, but thanks again :)

Comment: Yeah, works fine! Or almost... in the repositories, Akavache is used to get the data in the cache, and refecth it just after in case it has changed on the server. It means that GetMonthlyFocusPackages() or GetPackageMedias() are emitting results _two times_ (cached value, then the flreshly-loaded one).
It seems to cause a big mess with the query and the resulting list has 3 instances (at least) of a same media.
It's not in the original scope of the question, so I'm already accepting your answer...
(If I disable the refecth strategy, everything is fine)

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling - Can please post the full code so that I can see what's happening?